# Is “coordination ambiguity” a subset of “attachment ambiguity”?

Tags: syntax, ambiguity, coordination

As I understand:

- “attachment ambiguity” is when a constituent could be legally attached to more than one parts of a sentence.
- “coordination ambiguity” is when a modifier could be attached to an entire conjunction or to just a single component of the conjunction.  Ex: “delicious cookies and milk” could mean ⓐ “delicious cookies” + “milk”, or ⓑ “delicious cookies” + “delicious milk”.

These are treated separately in the articles I've seen, but “coordination ambiguity” seems to be a subset (kind) of “attachment ambiguity”.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  It's just a matter of terminology.  Like other constutuents, a coordinated constituent can be attached at one side of another constituent which is already ooordinated.  A long time ago, George Lakoff explored the theory that this sort of internal structure governs when a coordinate constiitutent can be exported and put after "together".  "[George and Harriet], and Herman jumped" = "George and Harriet jumped together with Herman."